# Django ms sql server 2014 Db configuration

Tags: python, sql-server, django

Database connection between django and MicroSoft SQL server

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'Hospital',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD':'upload',
        'HOST':'192.168.1.4',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    }
}
```

I tried some methods. but it repeatedly showing below error.

```
File "C:\Users\surendar\Desktop\pybatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 121, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: did you install mssql backend?

Comment: Yes already done. iklinac.

Comment: Did you `pip install django-mssql-backend` or `pip3 install django-mssql-backend`? Python 2.x and Python 3.x keep separate module hierarchies.